# ADO + VBA sheetname return value adds extra characters

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I am currently creating a script. The script will require to get the sheet names of an closed excel workbook using ADO. However, the sheet sometimes have excess characters in it such as single quote and dollar sign.

The result shows: Job list Sheet --> 'Job List Sheet'$ or Joblist --> Joblist$

I know this can be manipulated easily but can someone tell me why?

here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const SCHEMA_TABLES As Integer = 20
Private Const OPEN_FORWARD_ONLY As Integer = 0
Private Const LOCK_READ_ONLY As Integer = 1
Private Const CMD_TEXT As Long = 1
Private Const PROVIDER As String = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
Private Const XL_PROP As String = """Excel 12.0;HDR=No"""
Private Const SHEETS_FIELD_NAME As String = "TABLE_NAME"

Private Sub GetJoblist_Click()
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim oConn As Object
    Dim oRS As Object
    Dim connString As String
    Dim sql As String
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim sheetField As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim key As String
    Dim job_used As String
    Dim sheetfieldvalue As String

    Dim SelectedFile As String
    Dim Source_flow As Range, target_flow As Range
    Dim TP_location As String, TP_filename As String, TP_formula As String, getcellvalue As String

    'Define the path and file name
    fPath = TextBox1.Value

    'Define key word
    key = "Job"

    'Late bind the ADO objects
    Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    'Open conection
    connString = "Provider=" & PROVIDER & ";" & _
                 "Data Source=" & fPath & ";" & _
                 "Extended Properties=" & XL_PROP & ";"

    oConn.Open connString

    'Search for the sheet name containing your key
    'in the tables (ie sheets) schema
    found = False
    oRS.Open oConn.OpenSchema(SCHEMA_TABLES)
    i = 1
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Job_list"

    Do While Not oRS.EOF
        sheetField = oRS.Fields(SHEETS_FIELD_NAME).Value ' why does this returns a value with ' and '$?
        Cells(i, 18) = sheetField
        If InStr(sheetField, key) > 0 Or InStr(sheetField, UCase(key)) > 0 Then
            found = True
            If Right(sheetField, 2) = "$'" Then
             sheetfieldvalue = Left(sheetField, Len(sheetField) - 2)
             sheetfieldvalue = Right(sheetfieldvalue, Len(sheetfieldvalue) - 1)
             Cells(i, 17) = sheetfieldvalue
            Else:
                sheetfieldvalue = Left(sheetField, Len(sheetField) - 1)
                Cells(i, 17) = sheetfieldvalue
            End If
            Exit Do
        End If
        oRS.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    oRS.Close

    Set oRS = Nothing
    oConn.Close
    Set oConn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because that's the naming convention for Excel ADO.

> Table Naming Conventions
>
> There are several ways you can reference a table (or range) in an
>   Excel workbook: Use the sheet name followed by a dollar sign (for
>   example, [Sheet1$] or [My Worksheet$]). A workbook table that is
>   referenced in this manner consists of the entire used range of the
>   worksheet.
>
> oRS.Open "Select * from [Sheet1$]", oConn, adOpenStatic

read more: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278973